# Flask jinja2 table generation with variable

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, jinja2

I'd like to filter dynamically a flask generated table thanks to a variable set in JavaScript from another similar table.

Unfortunately, it seems that Javascript variables cannot be reused in Jinja2 contexts (because jinja2 contexts are run prior to Javascript).

In the example below, I'd like to filter the tasks with the project_id. This project_id was set thanks to the value selected in another table.

Note: I'd like to avoid to reload the page thanks to this solution.

```
    {% for Task in mytasks %}
    {% if Task.project_id == var_project_id %} <- Not working, the javascript variable is not recognized 
        <tr class="clickable-row">
        <td style="display:none;"> {{ Task.task_id }} </td>
        <td style="display:none;"> {{ Task.project_id }} </td>
        <td>{{ Task.title }}</td>
        <td class="task_description" > {{ Task.description }} </td>
        <td class="task_creation_date"> {{ Task.creation_date }} </td>
        </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question. Also AFAIK Jinja is processed serverside (while JavaScript runs client-side) - so you'd need to use something JavaScript based (either vanilla JS, jQuery or a full front-end framework)

Comment: Thanks a lot UnholySheep, it is much more clear now. Do you have any example working with hover-tables in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution thanks to a simple javascript function.

Here is it, just in case some one else has the same issue:

```
<script>    
//The project id is defined when the project is selected in a hover table
$('#myTableProject tbody tr').click(function (event) {
$('tr').not(this).removeClass('highlight');
$(this).addClass('highlight');
project_id = $(this).find('td.project_id').text();
//...
var tableTasks;
tableTasks = document.getElementById("myTableTasks");
tr = tableTasks.getElementsByTagName("tr");
// Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];// [1] is the column number you want to filter
if (td) {
  //each cell of the column [1] is compared to the project id
  if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(project_id) > -1) {
    tr[i].style.display = "";//the data is displayed
  } else {
    tr[i].style.display = "none";//the data is hidden
  }
} }
</script>
```

More info:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp